# Number of words in binary linear code starting with zero and unit

Tags: coding-theory

Is it true that in a binary linear code number of words, which start with zero, is always at least as much as words, which start with 1?

I have no idea how to prove or disprove it. Can you give me a hint how to start, please?

Comment: Induction on the dimension of the code. (Base case: the code of dimension 0, which contains only the all-0 word.)

Comment: And of course any code of dimension $n \ge 1$ can be written as the direct sum of two codes, of dimensions $n-1$ and $1$.